# MongoDB : Update array in array if all objects of the array match multiple conditions

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to update the array grades for a specific user. I want to push an object into grades if in the array there is no object that matches the semester and subject values.

Input :

```
   {
        "users": [
            {
                "userID": "id_1",
                "grades": [
                    {
                        "semester": 1,
                        "subject": "math",
                        "value": 15
                    },
                    {
                        "semester": 1,
                        "subject": "french",
                        "value": 15
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "userID": "id_2",
                "grades": [
                    {
                        "semester": 1,
                        "subject": "math",
                        "value": 18
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

For example if I want to push :

```
{
    "semester": 2,
    "subject": "french",
    "value": 16
}
```

for userID = id_1.

The result is :

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "userID": "id_1",
            "grades": [
                {
                    "semester": 1,
                    "subject": "math",
                    "value": 15
                },
                {
                    "semester": 1,
                    "subject": "french",
                    "value": 15
                },
                {
                    "semester": 2,
                    "subject": "french",
                    "value": 16
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "userID": "id_2",
            "grades": [
                {
                    "semester": 1,
                    "subject": "math",
                    "value": 18
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But also if I try to push

```
{
    "semester": 1,
    "subject": "french",
    "value": 10
}
```

for userID = id_1.

It won't update, because there is already an object that match "semester" : 1 and "subject" : "french"

I tried to use arrayFilter with array identifier to filter on userID first, but then I cannot achieve to apply the push condition on grades array.

```
{"$push":{ "users.$[user].grades": { "semester": 1, "subject": "math", "value" : 10 } }}
arrayFilter = [{"user.userID" : "id_1"}]
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a mix of `$not` with `$elemMatch` to achieve what you're aiming to, which translate to if no element of grades match the condition on semester & subject of the new one, then add it,

Here's how you can do it:

```js
db.users.update({
    "userID": "id_1",
    "grades": {
        "$not": {
            "$elemMatch": {
                "semester": 2,
                "subject": "french"
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    "$push": {
        "grades": {
            "semester": 2,
            "subject": "french",
            "value": 16
        }
    }
})
```